# html2pdf (TCPDF) problems and standards

Tags: html, tcpdf, html2pdf

I am using **html2pdf based on TCPDF**, but:

1. Content is overlapping fixed header and footer. Is there any way to set page so that header content and footer will not overlap?
2. If a table exceeds the page height, the whole table shifts to next page. I want only the part that does not fit the page to overflow to the next page.
3. Are there any coding standards and UI limitations in html2pdf?

Comment: Can you post additional code of html2pdf - TCPDF you use.?

Comment: In this TCPDF example http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.phps view example PDF here http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.pdf the 4rth table is split in two pages by default

Comment: Thanks for your initiative @PeterDarmis...actually the examples you are checking is just of TCPDF but if you google there is a difference between core TCPDF and html2pdf - TCPDF.

Comment: Why not just use markdown? you can generate PDF and HTML from markdown

Comment: please elaborate about markdown??

Comment: Show what you have till now